# Open RDP Connection window using jquery - client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to open RDP Connection window using jquery(client side) ?

My jquery code is given below,

```
$(function () {
        $(".RDPLink1").live('click', function () {
            var IPAddress = $(this).attr('id');  // ip or name of computer to connect

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                data: { strIPAddress: IPAddress },
                url: '<%=Url.Action("OpenRDPWindow","Home") %>',
                success: function (data) {                        
                }
            });
        });
```

I call the **Home** controller method, name is **OpenRDPWindow**, like

```
    public void OpenRDPWindow(string strIPAddress)
    {            
        Process objProcess = new Process();
        string exe = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
        if (exe != null)
        {               
            objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
            objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v " + strIPAddress;   // ip or name of computer to connect
            objProcess.Start();
        }            
    }
```

- Actually my need is, When the user click the href link in my page, we
  need to open RDP Window based on IPAddress...
- In my system using VS2010, it is working fine & it's open the RDP
  Window based on IPAddress, because i wrote the code in Server side(C#)
  to my system ...
- After i deploy the project in IIS, then user click the href link, the
  RDP(mstsc.exe) was running in Server machine(where i deploy my
  application).
- But i need to open the RDP window in user machine (Client side)...

How do i solve this using jquery or javascript? (or)  Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance....@@@

Comment: your RDP is opening because your developer machine is the server when you debug, but when you deploy it to the server it opens the RDP on the server, not to the user who triggered it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed the given below steps for solve this issue,

1) Jquery code is

```
$(function () {
    $(".RDPLink1").live('click', function () {
        var IPAddress = $(this).attr('id');  // ip or name of computer to connect
        window.location.href="http://path/home/OpenRDP?address="+IPAddress ;            
    });
});
```

2) I created a new .aspx page & write given below server side(C#) code in GET Method(Page load) for solve this issue

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult OpenRDP()
{
        string address = Request.QueryString["address"];
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.rdp", address));
        Response.Output.Write(string.Format(@"
screen mode id:i:2
session bpp:i:32
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
displayconnectionbar:i:1
disable wallpaper:i:1
disable full window drag:i:1
allow desktop composition:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:{0}
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:1
drivestoredirect:s:E:;
use multimon:i:0
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:2
redirectdirectx:i:1
use redirection server name:i:0", address));

        Response.End();
        return View();
}
```

It will open the RDP window from client's browser download option....

So, this is the one type of solution for this issue...

Answer (score 1):

> How do i solve this using jquery or javascript?

Wait a minute, you are opening a process on the server, not on the client computer. That's why your application doesn't work. For security reasons you cannot start processes on the client machine. Achieving this task through javascript only might be quite challenging. Companies such as [`LogMeIn`](http://www.logmein.com/) have implemented such interfaces, but there are years of work behind, not something that you might hope achieve in a couple of lines of code that someone will post you on Stack Overflow :-)

Some possibilities include [using an ActiveX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380809%28VS.85%29.aspx) which obviously impose that you have control over your clients environment. Another possibility is to use a Silverlight 5 Out-Of-Browser application running in Full Trust which allows you to start processes on the client, but it obviously has the same limitation as the first solution, it's just that ActiveX is kinda obsolete technology now.

Comment: Hi @Darin Dimitrov.. Thanks for your reply... You mean we cant do this in client computer? Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Depending on your environment, there might be some solutions. For example if you have total control over your clients machines, and they use IE, you might write an ActiveX control which starts a process on the client. But since ActiveX are now considered obsolete technology you might also consider an out-of-browser Silverlight 5 application which running in Full Trust which would allow you to start a process on the client computer. You can forget about pure javascript. For absolutely obvious security reasons, starting processes on the client is impossible.