# IE dropping vbscript but the activex terminal services control msrdp.ocx only works with vbscript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript, remote-desktop

Our clients use RDP sessions created by clicking a button on our site which uses the old MSRDP.cab file called in a webpage. We also utilize Virtual channels using a custom dll. Both our dll and the MSRDP.ocx are loaded through the object tag and cab files using VBScript.

As you might know, the orginal RDP connection script was written in VBScript. Apparently the ActiveX control will only work if called using VBScript. That has been working for over a decade. However the newer IE browsers and virtually all of the other browsers do not support VBScript.

I realize that I can call the new RDP program mstsc.exe from Javascript for a straight connection. However, we also pass information to the old ocx like the plugin parameters in Advancedsettings which include our dll that uses virtual channels. In addition, we pass the domain and username.

Maybe I'm searching in all the wrong places but I'm turning up no answers in trying to find how to run this ocx in javascript or another solution that would work. I'm thinking there has to be a replacement out there that I'm overlooking.

We are able to force our clients to use IE so we are currently having our clients with IE versions over 10 to use compatibility mode. However I'm sure at some point this may no longer work.

Has anyone out there had a similar problem that you have found a solution for? Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it yourself that in the future, your ActiveX may no longer work and supported so I strongly believe that you should invest your time in re-writing your app using a more modern approach instead.

Here's a link to a solution where it is using Jquery and ASP.NET to open an RDP connection:

[Open RDP Connection window using jquery - client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341711/open-rdp-connection-window-using-jquery-client-side)